# Brand name pronouncing

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation

I'm looking for a good website name, and was wondering how would people pronounce "Phourly".
Will it be confusing?

Comment: I think it would play pourly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your situation is the same as that which faced Donald Knuth when he chose the brand name "TeX" for his famous program. As he believed enough in his message ("tex" is in greek "art" as well as "crafts") and as he thought  that to communicate that message properly the greek pronunciation was the right one he set out in his work indicating that pronunciation: "tech", "ch"  as in  "loch" (Scottish language). Therefore it is not uncommon to find directives in all sorts of literature about LaTeX telling you how to pronounce that word. This means that the same scheme would probably be your lot. If you think your choice of pronunciation is worth the possible problems I explain why not go ahead, however unusual it is, and announce how you'd like the word to be pronounced. Otherwise, you might choose a more prudent path and settle for a simpler spelling and its evident pronunciation. It's interesting to know, nevertheless, that later on in his carreer Knuth claimed that he didn't mind how people chose to pronounce the name of his program.